# Displaying Images in Search Results

Tags: media, search

I have a Resource content type that has an image field (field type and widget are both 'image'); the standard image type.  The title of this field is 'Icon' and the machine name is 'field_icon'. I created my teaser so that the title, date, image, and description fields show and customized my search-result.tpl.php and template.php files so they are displaying the teaser/snippet. That works fine.

However, now I'd like to be able to format the returned results a bit more. I see how I can put HTML directly in the .tpl file, fine. But I want to customize the image field so it appears to the LEFT (float or align left) of the other returned teaser elements.

My problem is I can't figure out how to get the variable that represents the image so I can manipulate it in my .tpl file. I tried the following, but it just returns the number to indicate there IS an image or not:

```
$result['node']->'field-icon';
```

Can someone please tell me how to get the proper variable or link to the icon itself so I can manipulate it in my .tpl file?

Thank you.

Note, here's my current search-result.tpl.php code:

```
<li class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
  <div class="search-snippet-info">
    <?php if ($snippet): ?>
      <?php print $snippet; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like this will help:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_search_result()
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_search_result(&$variables) {    
    $node = $variables['result']['node'];
    if (is_object($node) && $node->nid) { // if the result is a node we can load the teaser
        $variables['teaser'] = node_view($node, 'teaser');
    }
}
```

That will provide the variable $teaser to your search template. In search-result.tpl.php you can then access your field data:

```
<div class="search-snippet-info">
    <?php print render($teaser['field_icon']); ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php print $url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a></h2>
    <?php if ($snippet): ?>
      <?php print $snippet; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```